# How to route to a specific method in cakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-routing

my route:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'homepage'));

Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard', 'admin' => true));
```

my Controller

```
class BrandsController extends AppController {

/**
 * Components
 *
 * @var array
 */
public $components = array('Paginator', 'Session', 'Flash');


var $paginate = array('limit' => 100);

/**
 * admin_index method
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function admin_index()
{      
  index method      
}
 public function admin_searches() 
{
     searches method
}
```

My link

```
<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'brands', 'action' => 'searches')); ?>
```

I have a admin_searches.ctp file which has hello world text as well.

Problem is: When i have a href link as,

```
<a href="<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'brands','action' => 'admin_index')); ?>">Brands List</a>
```

it works fine and displays the index page. Now when i want to display a search page "admin_searches,ctp" it wont. How may I route in the link or amend route file so that when i call the above link it invokes search method in my controller class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a authentication issue. Everytime i try to create a new file eg: admin_search and a controller method called admin_search it echoes "you are not permitted to acess this location." Therefore, to overcome this issue i had to include authentication of a method in beforeFilter();

```
public function beforeFilter() {
            parent::beforeFilter();
            $this->Auth->allow('admin_searches');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your admin_searches action is in your BrandsController you should print links in the view like this:

```
<?= $this->Html->link('admin searches',['controller' => 'brands', 'action'=>'admin_searches']); ?>
```

It will write the `<a>` tags for you as well. You are probably going to have to sub out the controller and action names, i just guessed. But it is the way to use the HTML helper to generate links

**Rewriting url to map to your action**

Its pretty straight forward in the documentation. in your routes.php file add something like:

```
Router::connect(
    '/brands/searches',
    array('controller' => 'brands', 'action' => 'admin_searches')
);
```

now /brands/searches will go to the admin_searches action in your brands controller

> https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#connecting-routes

**UPDATE**

you have told me the link generated is `/magnus_backend/admin/brands/searches` There is a couple of ways to route to it. I would probably look at rewriting the base url but this should work

```
Router::connect(
    '/magnus_backend/admin/brands/searches',
    array('controller' => 'brands', 'action' => 'admin_searches')
);
```

Comment: How do I return a view using this link. For instance i have a view page called admin_searches.ctp. so when i click this link how will I return a view.  I actually work on laravel, this one problem i got on the job where i have to solve it and i got no clue or experience in cake php.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you tell me what url you want to use and what action in your brands controller you want to access? The actual url you would see in the nav bar of your browser

Comment: Additionally, when i click the link above it will redirect me to admin_index page

Comment: I just want a url like you gave me which will invoke method called admin_searches() in my controller as shown above in my code. Same thing works fine with index, view, edit methods in controller. I just added a new method called admin_searches, now i want it to be included in my link as you gave me, which will then display a page called admin_searches.ctp

Comment: i dont know which link you are referring to. Normal cake convention is to name the action the same as the view. so if your url uses the same action name as in the controller and that is the same name as the view it should all render nicely

Comment: Yes. try my first block of code with the `<?= $this->Html...` it will render the link you are asking for. Routing is automagic in cake so you do not need to define the route like laravel. try it and you will see. (no need to touch route.php for it to work)

Comment: The above link does generate a valid url like below:
<li><a href="/magnus_backend/admin/brands/searches">admin searches</a></li>
However, when i click on the link it will redirect me to the index page.

Comment: what is the `/magnus/admin` part of your url? Anyway, try my update.

Comment: magnus is server name or should say base url, admin is after loggin in to the backend CMS..

Comment: Sorry, magnus is a folder name where all my cake application are. it is in development server http://clients.view9.com.np/magnus_backend/admin/brands

Comment: Thats fine. So im guessing adding my updated `Router::connect` to your routes.php file did not work?

Comment: You guessed it right.. I have tried every workaround possible just cant get it right .. My only problem is how do I display a page using controller method..

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to go through the tutorial on the cakephp website to get an idea if cakes default mapping and routing conventions